# Add database value for multialarm

Tags: java, alarm

I'm new in java and I need help for adding my database value for multi alarm (desktop not Android).  This is my code for the alarm class:

```
public class Alarm { 
Thread t; int str = 0;
Connection conn = null ;

public void checkAlarm(int d,int m,int hh,int mm,final String ampm,final String message){ 
final int a=hh,b=m,c=d,f=mm;                
if(ampm.equals("AM"))
{ str=0; }
else if(ampm.equals("PM"))
{
 str=1;
}
final boolean whileloop=true;
t=new Thread(){ 
      private Object ac;
public void run()
{ 
    while(whileloop==true) 
{ 
    Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
    //DATE
    int date1=d.get(Calendar.DATE); 
    int month=d.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //TIME
    int hours=d.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
    int mins=d.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
    int str1=d.get(Calendar.AM_PM); 
    if(c==date1&&f==month&&a==hours&&b==mins&&st­r==str1) 
    {
        FrameNotification a = new FrameNotification();     
        a.setVisible(true);    
        break;                
    }
} 
} };

t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
t.start();
}
```

I try this and it's work (without database value) like this :

```
       Alarm a=new Alarm();
       a.checkAlarm(29,((1)-1),3,19,"PM","X­D");
```

the problem is I don't know how to set

```
a.checkAlarm(29,((1)-1),3,19,"PM","X­D");
```

into

```
 a.checkAlarm(//insert database value here?);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class RuleDBConnection {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuleDBConnection.class);

public static class DBInfo {
    String host;
    int port;
    String database;
    String user;
    String password;
    String table;
    String queueName;
    String timeZoneID;
    int fetchSize;
    DBType dbType = DBType.MYSQL;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public DBType getDbType() {
        return dbType;
    }

    public void setDbType(DBType dbType) {
        this.dbType = dbType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this,
                ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }

    public static enum DBType {
        ORACLE, MYSQL
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection(DBInfo dbInfo) throws SQLException {
    try {
        String url = null;
        if (dbInfo.getDbType() == DBInfo.DBType.MYSQL) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s", dbInfo.getHost(),
                    dbInfo.getPort(), dbInfo.getDatabase());
        } else {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            url = String.format("jdbc:oracle:thin:@%s:%d:%s", dbInfo.host,
                    dbInfo.port, dbInfo.database);
        }
        logger.info("url=>{}", url);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbInfo.user,
                dbInfo.password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Using this code snippet, you can directly get connection to db, and use normal mysql queries.

Comment: I've been change function into void, so it works well now and Thank you so much for answering my problem, i appreciate it :)